# Force the screen reader to read a label

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, accessibility

I am developing an application using accessibility properties. I have some buttons that increment and decrement some values showed in labels. Is it possible somehow force the screen reader to read a label when a blind user changes the values?

Answer (score 0):

Support for **aria-live** is spotty.

Seeing a code example would be handy, but if you are always putting focus on the field then perhaps you want to use aria-label with some good messaging instead as this is better supported and will be spoken when the field gets focus.

```
<label for="foo">Field Label</label>
<input type="text" id="foo" aria-label="Field Label. Note: If you are using a screen reader…">
```

Note: The screen reader reads the value when ever there is focus so after clicking the button check where your focus resides.

```
 1. Probably worth a read: https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2014/03/screen-reader-support-aria-live-regions/
 2. An example from JAWS: ARIA https://www.freedomscientific.com/SurfsUp/AriaLiveRegions.htm
```

OR
Accessibility - live region in Xamarin.Forms

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/feedback_text_view"
     android:accessibilityLiveRegion="polite" />
```

Please follow for more help = https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/basic-android-accessibility/#6

Hope will help you

Comment: I didn't add code because I don't think that I would help. When I change values using buttons, the last tapped button has the focus. If I change button's accessibility text, it is read. But I would like to read non focused label text too. Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: For that there is option that is in my mind is aria-live. A screen reader can only focus on one part of the page at a time. If something changes elsewhere on the page, there’s a good chance a screen reader user will be oblivious to it. When the update takes place within an ARIA live region, a screen reader is automatically notified (wherever its focus is at the time), and it conveys the updated content to the user.

Comment: Please follow this url once, it has the same example  
 "https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2014/03/screen-reader-support-aria-live-regions/"   just set aria-live="polite" on that div in which your dynamic value is updating.

Comment: But can I use this on Xamarin.Forms? It seem it is for HTML

Comment: @Jon, as you use other accessibility tags in the Xamarin in the same way you have to use this , please try once you might get success , aria-live forces the screen reader to read and please vote me if you get success thanks.

Comment: @Jon, i have added the property that you can use it for aria-live in Xamarin, i think this will help you to achieve your desired.

Comment: It seems that it is not implemented in Xamarin.Forms: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8805